# Why do Coq recursion principles pass along both the substructure and the result of the recursive call?

Tags: coq

After examining a few different recursion principles generated for different recursive data types, I noticed that in the recursive case, substructures are passed along with the result of the recursive call on the substructure.

For example, doing `Print list_rect` gives:

```
list_rect =
fun (A : Type) (P : list A -> Type) (f : P nil)
  (f0 : forall (a : A) (l : list A), P l -> P (a :: l)%list) =>
fix F (l : list A) : P l :=
  match l as l0 return (P l0) with
  | nil => f
  | (y :: l0)%list => f0 y l0 (F l0)
  end
     : forall (A : Type) (P : list A -> Type),
       P nil ->
       (forall (a : A) (l : list A), P l -> P (a :: l)%list) ->
       forall l : list A, P l
```

In the pattern match, the cons case looks like `(y :: l0)%list => f0 y l0 (F l0)`.  Why does `f0` take both `l0` and the result of recursively calling `F` on `l0`?  What are situations when you need access to the tail of the list when you've already computed the result of calling `F` on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you need the induction hypothesis, you need the tail of the list because it appears in its type: to write `P l`, `l` needs to be in scope.

Now if you weren't bothered about types, a good reason to have both the tail of the list and the recursive call is efficiency: computing the tail is linear in the size of the list but grabbing it on the way is constant time. The prototypical example of this type of issue is [the definition of the predecessor function for unary natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Derivation_of_predecessor_function) when you only have access to the iterator and not the recursor.

Comment: More on the *recursor* vs the *iterator*, can be found in [PFPL](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/pfpl/2nded.pdf), sect. 9.1 (System T).

Comment: Is it appropriate to call the special case where the tail is not required `fold`?  Is there a name for the special case where you only need the tail?